# Creating a 1PPS signal froma a 10 MHz CMOS Output Signal

Tags: signal, generator, pulse

Is it possible to "create" a 1PPS signal using an [Agilent 8165A](https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/08165-90005.pdf) signal generator? We currently don't have a way of testing a 1PPS signal directly, so we're looking at "making our own" for the time being. The thought process is to use an atomic clock that can provide a precise 10 MHz CMOS output at 3.3 Vpp. That signal would then go into a signal generator's External Input connector. Using the signal generator, our goal is to take the input and create a pulse that meets a specific pulse-width, specific rise time, and can amplify the signal to a 10 Vpp. I have already connected the 10 MHz reference to the signal generator, but I am lost on what to do next to get the specific pulse-width to mimic a 1PPS signal. I could use any inputs or ideas on how to get started to create a specific pulse-width.

Comment: Do you really need the extreme accuracy of an atomic clock?

Comment: Which signal generator are you using?

Comment: @Sparky256 That's part of my requirement. Got no way around it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm using the Agilent 8165A

Comment: What do you think a "PPS signal" is other than a pulse every second? Sounds like you have more criteria than just a PPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that signal generator can produce 1PPS, with or without an external reference, but only if you can live with a 20%, 50%, or 80% duty cycle. If you need other pulse widths, you'll have to follow this with a separate pulse generator. Even something as simple as a 555 could generate 10V pulses for you, depending on how precise the edges and widths need to be.